# Plot clprofiles function without hitting enter each time

Tags: r, plot, cluster-analysis

I'm looking for a way to get all plots of the variables without hitting enter each time.
if you're familiar with this function clprofiles of Kprototype, you know this message `Hit <Return> to see next plot:`, i want to see all plots of the variables at once.
Now i've tried doing a 'for loop' after the instruction `clprofiles(kpres, df)` :

```
    clprofiles(kpres, df)
for (i in 1:length(t)) {
  print("
        ")

}
```

But it's useless.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case, you will have to override the default behaviour of `clprofiles`. Add this new function `my.clprofiles` to your script:

```
my.clprofiles <- function(object, x, vars = NULL, col = NULL){
  library(RColorBrewer)
  if(length(object$cluster) != nrow(x)) stop("Size of x does not match cluster result!")
  if(is.null(vars)) vars <- 1:ncol(x)
  if(!is.numeric(vars)) vars <- sapply(vars, function(z) return(which(colnames(x)==z)))
  if(length(vars) < 1) stop("Specified variable names do not match x!")
  if(is.null(col)){
    k <- max(unique(object$cluster))
    if(k > 2)  col <- brewer.pal(k, "Set3")
    if(k == 2) col <- c("lightblue","orange")
    if(k == 1) col <- "lightblue"
  }
  clusids <- sort(unique(object$cluster)) 
  if(length(col) != max(clusids)) warning("Length of col should match number of clusters!")

  #REMOVE PROMPT
  #par(ask=TRUE)

  par(mfrow=c(2,2))

  for(i in vars){
    if(is.numeric(x[,i])){
      boxplot(x[,i]~object$cluster, col = col, main = colnames(x)[i])
      legend("topright", legend=clusids, fill = col)
    } 
    if(is.factor(x[,i])){
      tab <- table(x[,i], object$cluster)
      for(j in 1:length(object$size)) tab[,j] <- tab[,j]/object$size[j]
      barplot(t(tab), beside = TRUE, main = colnames(x)[i], col = col)
    } 
  }
  invisible()
}
```

And then you can call it once without having to hit Enter:

```
my.clprofiles(kpres,x)
```

which produces the same plot as in the first answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can override three of the four prompts (but not the first one) since the plotting method is within the `clprofiles` command. If your goal is just to get all the plots to print on a single plot, this will do it:

```
library(clustMixType)

# Example from documentation
n   <- 100;    prb <- 0.9;    muk <- 1.5 
clusid <- rep(1:4, each = n)
x1 <- sample(c("A","B"), 2*n, replace = TRUE, prob = c(prb, 1-prb))
x1 <- c(x1, sample(c("A","B"), 2*n, replace = TRUE, prob = c(1-prb, prb)))
x1 <- as.factor(x1)
x2 <- sample(c("A","B"), 2*n, replace = TRUE, prob = c(prb, 1-prb))
x2 <- c(x2, sample(c("A","B"), 2*n, replace = TRUE, prob = c(1-prb, prb)))
x2 <- as.factor(x2)
x3 <- c(rnorm(n, mean = -muk), rnorm(n, mean = muk), rnorm(n, mean = -muk), rnorm(n, mean = muk))
x4 <- c(rnorm(n, mean = -muk), rnorm(n, mean = muk), rnorm(n, mean = -muk), rnorm(n, mean = muk))
x <- data.frame(x1,x2,x3,x4)
kpres <- kproto(x, 4)
```

Then you can make the plot by preparing with `par` first:

```
> par(mfrow=c(2,2))
> clprofiles(kpres, x)
Hit <Return> to see next plot: 
>
```

And it produces:

[image]

Comment: Thats a really good idea thank you. But i have too many variables with so much levels so the solution of getting all the plots in one plot does not suit my case. I want a  to plot each variable individually. Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution that shows the plots in an external window (full screen) and instead of presing "enter" each time, you just have to click

```
dev.new(width=5,height=4,noRStudioGD = TRUE)
clprofiles(kpres,df)
```